# Bizarre path description

Tags: filesystems, path

I have a checked out a project with file hierarchy:

```
REPO/project/src/multiple sub-directories here
```

I am reading some documentation and at a certain point I have to create a file config.properties and put it into 2 locations specified by that:

1. `project/src/config.properties`
2. `project/../../config.properties`

The point 1 is obvious but the 2 I didn't understand it? Is it wrong or it's me?

Comment: Is the documentation you're following available online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
REPO/project/src/multiple sub-directories here
```

So these would be relative paths, not absolute paths (ie they don't start with a / to indicate the root)

```
project/src/config.properties
```

Would translate to  REPO/project/src/config.properties

```
project/../../config.properties
```

would translate to REPO/config.properties  because you change into project, then back two levels.

You can create symlinks to config.properties whereever you like, extra links won't mess anything up, and each one will use up one inode and no disk space.
If the real file is REPO/config.properties then this will symlink other files to that one.

```
ln -s REPO/config.properties  REPO/project/src/
```